# Why are Excel's camera tool and paste as picture cropping and resizing?

Tags: excel, image, copy-paste, paste

When I copy and paste as values or use the camera tool (essential for dashboards, VBA driven reports, etc.), the pasted/camera snapped image doesn't line up with the chosen columns.

I've got the answer to this (see below), but this stumped me for some time.

[image: Excel cropping & resizing error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here happens (and is fixed by) the native content resizing of windows. If "Change the size of text, apps and other items" isn't 100% (e.g. 125%), and especially if it flags in red that you need to log out and back in for applications to pick up the change, excel and many other products will handle screen shots very weirdly.

So this isn't a solution in excel. That's what stumped me, and buggered up (technical term) a number of my dashboards. FYI!

[image: windows resizing dialog]